# C#, .Net and wrapping Writeline for custom logging

Tags: c#, .net

I want to write a very simple logging method. It will basically wrap `WriteLine(...)`.  It should take any number of parameters. The first will either be a `StreamWriter` object or `null`. If the first object is `null` then it should use `Console.Writeline()...` otherwise the `StreamWriter` object.

I have seen that I should perhaps be using the `params ...` method parameter keyword, à la:

```
private static void MyLog(params object[] list) {
    if (list.Length <= 0) {
        throw new ArgumentException("Parameter list is empty.");
    }
    if (list.Length <= 2)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Parameter list is too short.");
    }

    var log = (StreamWriter) list[0];

    if (log != null) {
        log.WriteLine(list.Skip(1).Take(list.Length - 1));
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine(list.Skip(1).Take(list.Length - 1));
    }
}
```

This is called as:

```
try {
    var exePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
    var dirPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(exePath);
    var logFile = dirPath + "\\myLog.log";
    _log = File.AppendText(logFile);
    _log.AutoFlush = true;
    MyLog(_log, "----- START ----- {0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} -----", DateTime.Now);
} catch (Exception e) {
    _log = null;
    MyLog(null, e.Message);
}
...
MyLog(_log, "{0}:AD property {1} is null", username, property);
...
```

I was really hoping that the `list.Skip(1).Take(list.Length - 1)` construct would do an "array slice" and feed the 1..nth list objects to `WriteLine` and that it would do the right thing. Instead I get a stream of

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+<TakeIterator>d__25`1[System.Object]
```

How does one correctly wrap `Writeline` for such things?

Is there a better way to handle this sort of string interpolation logging to file or console?

Comment: you want the `ToList` or `ToArray` functions on the Enumerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    private static void MyLog(StreamWriter sw, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        if (sw == null)
            Console.WriteLine(format, args);
        else 
            sw.WriteLine(format, args);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

The general idea for what you want already exists in the framework, albeit with a somewhat different API.

Take a look at the [`System.Diagnostics.Trace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.trace?view=netframework-4.7.2) type. It has a [`WriteLine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.trace.writeline?view=netframework-4.7.2) method, and it works by letting you attach one or more [`TraceListener`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.tracelistener?view=netframework-4.7.2) objects, of which the framework provides [`ConsoleTraceListener`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.consoletracelistener?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [`TextWriterTraceListener`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.textwritertracelistener?view=netframework-4.7.2) (for files) out of the box, as well as others.

You can also make your own `TraceListener` to do things like log to a database or re-implement existing listeners to add features like automatically including timestamp or path information.

Sadly, `Trace.WriteLine()` is missing some of the expected overloads. This was more of problem until recently, but now that we have interpolated strings it's no big deal.

In this case, you would build your own TraceListener type (inherit from `TextWriterTraceListener` and most of the work is done for you) which attempts to append to a log file, but writes to the Console if an exception is thrown. Later on, the code just looks like this, and you get all of the features you wanted:

```
Trace.WriteLine($"{username}:AD property {property} is null");
```

At very least, it's much better practice to provide overloads to decide whether to use a streamwriter or console, like this:

```
private static void MyLog(string format, params object[] list) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(format, list);
}

private static void MyLog(StreamWriter log, string format, params object[] list) 
{
    log.WriteLine(format, list);
}
```

Again, that is **MUCH** better practice. But if you really want your existing code, replace the `Take()` calls with `ToArray()`. Then you match up with what the existing `WriteLine()` overloads expect.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that your first parameter is a StreamWriter, change the signature to reflect that:

```
private static void MyLog(StreamWriter log, params object[] list) {
```

If you know the what type the rest of the objects are, I'd type them too.

The number of elements in `list` will never be less than 0:

```
if (list.Length <= 0) {
```

The `Take` method is only needed if you want a subset of elements from the beginning, not the rest of them, and since you already skipped one, you just want the rest:

```
list.Skip(1)
```

The above, however, is not necessary, since we changed the signature of your method, so you just want your full `list` array.

The WriteLine method doesn't know how you want the array of unknown objects formatted. Even if it was a `string[]`, I'm not sure it would know what to do with it. If we assume that it's a `string[]`, you could do the following:

```
WriteLine(list.Aggregate((current, next) => current + Environment.NewLine + next))
```

If that doesn't help, please specify which content you expect, and how you'd like it formatted.